# install nvidia digits - ImportError: No module named wtforms

Tags: python, deep-learning, nvidia, caffe, digits

```
  ___ ___ ___ ___ _____ ___
 |   \_ _/ __|_ _|_   _/ __|
 | |) | | (_ || |  | | \__ \
 |___/___\___|___| |_| |___/ 5.0.0-rc.1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jj/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/home/jj/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/jj/digits/digits/__main__.py", line 66, in <module>
main()
  File "/home/jj/digits/digits/__main__.py", line 49, in main
    import digits.config
  File "digits/config/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import caffe
  File "digits/config/caffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from digits.utils import parse_version
  File "digits/utils/__init__.py", line 158, in <module>
    from . import constants, image, time_filters, errors, forms, routing, auth
  File "digits/utils/forms.py", line 5, in <module>
    import wtforms
ImportError: No module named wtforms
```

which python

/home/jj/anaconda2/bin/python

which pip
/home/jj/anaconda2/bin/pip

But 
sudo pip install wtforms

```
The directory '/home/jj/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/jj/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wtforms in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

It might be path problem... Could you help..?

Comment: Is `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` in your pythonpath?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the canonical use cases for virtualenv.  Because you are using sudo to install, there are now two potential paths where items could be installed:  User and Root paths.

Try creating a virtualenv:

then pip install from inside virtualenv.